# Conflict between comment character and headers to import DF with read.table

Tags: r, import, read.table

How could I import a file :

- starting with an undefined number of comment lines
- followed by a line with headers, some of them containing the comment character which is used to identify the comment lines above?

For example, with a file like this:

```
# comment 1
# ...
# comment X
c01,c#02,c03,c04
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

Then:

```
myDF = read.table(myfile, sep=',', header=T)
```

> Error in read.table(myfile, sep = ",", header = T) :    more columns
>   than column names

The obvious problem is that `#` is used as comment character to announce comment lines, but also in the headers (which, admittedly, is bad practice, but I have no control on this).

The number of comment lines being unknown *a priori*, I can't even use the `skip` argument. Also, I don't know the column names (not even their number) before importing, so I'd really need to read them from the file.

Any solution beyond manually manipulating the file?

Comment: `readLines` to import the whole thing as strings, then clean it up into a standard format.

Comment: Cleanup the file before you bring it into R.  Maybe you can go to the source and handle things there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easy enough to count the number of lines that start with a comment, and then skip them.

```
csvfile <- "# comment 1
# ...
# comment X
c01,c#02,c03,c04
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8"

# return a logical for whether the line starts with a comment.
# remove everything from the first FALSE and afterward
# take the sum of what's left
start_comment <- grepl("^#", readLines(textConnection(csvfile)))
start_comment <- sum(head(start_comment, which(!start_comment)[1] - 1))

# skip the lines that start with the comment character
Data <- read.csv(textConnection(csvfile),
                 skip = start_comment,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note that this will work with `read.csv`, because in `read.csv`, `comment.char = ""`. If you must use `read.table`, or must have `comment.char = #`, you may need a couple more steps.

```
start_comment <- grepl("^#", readLines(textConnection(csvfile)))
start_comment <- sum(head(start_comment, which(!start_comment)[1] - 1))

# Get the headers by themselves.
Head <- read.table(textConnection(csvfile),
                   skip = start_comment,
                   header = FALSE,
                   sep = ",",
                   comment.char = "",
                   nrows = 1)

Data <- read.table(textConnection(csvfile),
                   sep = ",",
                   header = FALSE,
                   skip = start_comment + 1,
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# apply column names to Data
names(Data) <- unlist(Head)
```